# Array in get parameter Rest Assured

Tags: java, rest-assured

I need to send the following GET request with Rest Assured:

```
http://some.url.com/path?filter[key1]=value1&filter[key2]=value2
```

I was trying to do it with **queryParams** and **formParams**, but it constructs params as `filter={"key":"value"}`.

In JQuery I can do this with:

```
$.param({filter:{key1:"value1"}})
```

Comment: Another option is:
 `given().
 queryParam("filter[key1]", "value1").
 queryParam("filter[key2]", "value2").
when().
 get("some.url.com").
then().`

Answer (score 2):

According to the Rest-Assured usage guide

> Parameters can also be set directly on the url:
>
> ..when().get("/name?firstName=John&lastName=Doe");

Could you not just use a formatted `String` with the values you want if you are not getting the desired result from the `queryParam` and `formParam` methods?

Comment: This is an option, but not very convenient.

Suppose I want to send GET request with several filters values.
With parameters set directly on the url it will look like:
```

Comment: I can't see what your example is meant to be? True but you could hold all of your filters in a `Map<String, String>` and then build the parameters `String` from the map entries and concatenate it to the end of the URL?

Comment: I would like to do it something like this:
`given().baseUri(uri).queryParams("filter", params).when.get(/path);`

where *params* is already defined Map<String,String>: {key1:"value1", key2:"value2", key3:"value3"} 

But probably, I will use your option.

Comment: Sounds like you should open a pull request on https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured, @art_tykh.

Answer (score 0):

I did similar thing using following way

```
String path = "path?";
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("q", search));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lang", lang));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sort", sort));
            path = path + URLEncodedUtils.format(nameValuePairs, "utf-8");
            System.out.println("REQUEST URL " + path);
            response = given().auth().preemptive().basic(user, pass).when().get(path);
```